# Print Object Value from Variable in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, model

I want to display object value that i save in variable. How it works in NodeJS?

Here's my code:

```html
const modelMateris = require("../models/materi");

var obj = modelMateris.find().exec((err, result)=>{
  if(result){
     return (result);
  } else (err);
})

console.log(obj);
```

I got undefined output. So how to print it in NodeJS? Thanks.

Comment: Log it inside the callback. Or use a promise that resolves to the result.

Answer (score 1):

if `modelMateris.find().exec` function returns promise then you can follow the below approach to print the result

```
var obj = await modelMateris.find().exec();
console.log(obj);
```

if promise not supported, then you can print values as below.

```
modelMateris.find().exec((err, result)=>{
  if(result){
    console.log(result);
  } else (err);
})
```